# Jquery ('div').on function tag selection

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm fairly new to JQuery, was wondering about the .on() function. For example:

```
$('div').on('click', function() {$(this).toggleClass('show-description');});
```

the first bit of code is selecting all the 'div' elements within my HTML file and is listening for a click event. Then, it will toggle my 'show-description' class 'on' and 'off' for the last div I clicked on.

```
<div class="show-description"> ......</div>
```

What if I want to specify only a specific class I defined within a div tag to listen for my event?

I've tried:

```
$('div.about').on('click', function() {$(this).toggleClass('show-description');});
```

Where I have defined within HTML:

```
<body>
 <div class="clearfix"> 
  <div class="column">
    <ul>
     <li id='about'> <span>About Me</span> </li>
      ......
   </div>
 </div>
```

Yet I don't get my 'show-description' declarations to activate . I've already tried reading up on the API .on() method, as well as going through Stack and can't seem to find anything to help with this. **I'm not looking for direct answer**  just a ***nudge in the right direction.***

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the `<div class="about">` on your code?

Comment: Correct, that's the wrong notation. I've tried this.....
     $("div.column").on("click", "#about", function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('show-description');
});     

 Still, doesn't seem like I'm asking it to listen correctly to the right element...

Comment: @RyanAnderson Actually what you wrote there, `$("div.column").on("click", "#about", function(){ })`, should work. I tried it, but I use `alert("test")`inside that click listener, and it works.

Comment: @Dekel, I did, thanks for the help your answer was clear, concise and was exactly what i was looking for! Appreciate all the help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('div.about')` will select all `div` elements that has the `about` class. In your example - none of the `div` elements has that class.

The only `about` you have in your example is an `id` (which is not a class) and it's in the `li` element.

You might want this: `$('li#about').on('click', ...`

Check the following snippet:

```js
$('div.about').on('click', function() {$(this).toggleClass('show-description');});


$('li#about').on('click', function() {$(this).toggleClass('show-description');});
```

```css
.show-description {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clearfix"> 
  <div class="column">
    <ul>
      <li id='about'> <span>About Me</span> </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="about">This div has the "about" class</div>
</div>
```

> In the example above you can see that there are two elements you can click - the `li#about` and the `div.about`. Each click will toggle a red border to the element that was clicked.

As a side note (for the above example), we could do exactly the same with

```
$('div.about, li#about').on('click', ...
```

Answer (score 1):

> What if I want to specify only a specific class I defined **within** a div
>   tag to listen for my event?

My example below doesn't use `class` and `on` function, though I believe you can get the idea. Assume you have below HTML code:

```
<ul class="topnav">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2
    <ul>
    <li>Nested item 1</li>
    <li>Nested item 2</li>
    <li>Nested item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

If you want to do something with every `li` **within** `ul`, then you use this:

```
$( "ul.topnav li" ).css( "border", "3px double red" );
```

Though, if you want to do something with every `li` **within and direct child of** `ul`, then you can do something like this:

```
$( "ul.topnav > li" ).css( "border", "3px double red" );
```

For your specific case you can do this:

```
$( "div #about" ).on( ... );
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Not directly helpful for this specific example but definitely will refer back to this in the future. Thanks!